# screen saver function in WPF app not working well with three monitors

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application I've been working on and I built some functionality to be able to launch it and leave it running like a screen saver on a PC. It maximizes the primary window on the main monitor and then opens up a blackout black background window on all other monitors. The problem I'm having is that it does not seem to work well with more then two monitors. 3+ monitors and the blackout is not appearing on all of them.

Code to launch all the windows:

```
foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
    {
        Blackout window = new Blackout();
        window.Left = s.WorkingArea.Left;
        window.Top = s.WorkingArea.Top;
        window.Width = s.WorkingArea.Width;
        window.Height = s.WorkingArea.Height;
        window.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        BigScreenScreenSaver window = new BigScreenScreenSaver();
        window.Left = s.WorkingArea.Left;
        window.Top = s.WorkingArea.Top;
        window.Width = s.WorkingArea.Width;
        window.Height = s.WorkingArea.Height;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting bounds instead of working area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bounds, working area excludes taskbar and many other

```
foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    if (s != Screen.PrimaryScreen)
    {
        Blackout window = new Blackout();
         window.Left = s.Bounds.Left;
          window.Top = s.Bounds.Top;
          window.Width = s.Bounds.Width;
           window.Height = s.Bounds.Height;
        window.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        BigScreenScreenSaver window = new BigScreenScreenSaver();
        window.Left = s.Bounds.Left;
          window.Top = s.Bounds.Top;
          window.Width = s.Bounds.Width;
           window.Height = s.Bounds.Height;
        window.Show();
    }

}
```

Comment: window does not contain a definition for Bounds. i do have ClipTobounds if this is the same thing?

Comment: Isn't it a Windows form ?

Comment: WPF. i'm importing system.windows.forms to do certain things but that had no effect on finding bounds.

Comment: Try the changed answer

Comment: That worked out. it now displays on all 4 monitors....its still a sketchy way to do it to begin with so it looks a little weird depending on the setup of the PC but it works for now. Thanks for the help!